# Confirmation of Proof: $2a_n^2 - 1 = \left\{b_n^2 : \forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{>1}, \ a_n = 6a_{n - 1} - 1 \ \land \ a_1 = 1\right\}$

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

We have the following equation $2a^2 - 1 = b^2$.

> Notation:
>
> $a_1 = 1$
>
> $a_n = \text{ $n^{th}$ value of $a$ to satisfy the equation.}$
>
> $b_n = \text{ $n^{th}$ value of $b$ to satisfy the equation.}$

Through trial and error, I figured out that $a_n = 6a_{n - 1} - 1$ for which $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>1}$ but I do not know why. Assuming it is true, how can I prove this? If I substitute:

$$2a_n^2 - 1 = b_n^2 \Rightarrow 2(6a_{n - 1} - 1)^2 - 1 = b_n^2 \Rightarrow 2(36a_{n - 1}^2 + 1 - 12a_{n - 1}) - 1 = b_n^2 \therefore 24(3a_{n - 1}^2 - a_{n - 1}) + 1 = b_n^2$$

But now what do I do from here?

Thank you in advance.

---

**Edit:**

I had no idea this was in the form of a *negative Pell equation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are solutions to the [negative Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_negative_Pell_equation)
$$x^2-2y^2=-1.$$
The general solution is given by $(x,y)=(b_n,a_n)$ where
$$b_n+a_n\sqrt2=(1+\sqrt2)^{2n-1}=(1+\sqrt2)(3+2\sqrt2)^{n-1}.$$
Therefore
$$(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})=(3a_n+2b_n,4a_n+3b_n).$$
The first solutions are $(1,1)$, $(5,7)$, $(29,41)$, $(169,239)$.
But $169\ne6\times29-1$.

Comment: I never knew this was a *Pell Equation*! I have never even heard of it! But I do feel proud to know that I have been looking into this via re-creational maths, without even knowing it has *been* discovered before :)

Comment: Well, congratulations Lord Shark :) $$(+1) \ \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Comment: Are the solutions $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})$ always $\pm 1 \pmod 6$?

Comment: Yes, modulo $6$, the solutions $(a_n,b_n)$ go $(1,1)$, $(-1,1)$, $(-1,-1)$, $(1,-1)$, $(1,1),\ldots$.

Comment: Thanks! I was just wondering :)

Answer (score 1):

no, actually, the correct relations are
$$ a_{n+2} = 6 a_{n+1} - a_n,  $$
$$ b_{n+2} = 6 b_{n+1} - b_n.  $$ This comes from Cayley-Hamilton for the matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3 & 4 \\
2 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$

==================================

Let's do both sides for $a.$

$$ 6 a_{n+1} - a_n = 6(3a_n +4b_n) - a_n = 17 a_n + 24 b_n.  $$
$$ a_{n+2} = 3 a_{n+1} + 4 b_{n+1} = 3(3 a_n + 4 b_n) + 4 (2 a_n + 3 b_n) = 17 a_n + 24 b_n  $$

Comment: I like this answer, but I do not entirely know how to work with matrices, although I am familiar with them. $(+1)$ though on the other hand :)

Comment: @user477343   no matter. You can recover the two recurrences by carefully writing out what Shark's answer says about $a_{n+2}$ and $b_{n+2}.$ Not difficult, give it a try.

Comment: alright then. Thanks heaps! :)) $\ldots$ Ahhhh ok I understand now, and how Shark's answer relates to the matrix, concerning $(a_{n + 1}, \ b_{n + 1})$

Comment: @user, I wrote it out for $a_{n+2}.$ Maybe you can do $b_{n+2}.$