# Trying to reduce a quadratic system to linear solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms

I have coprime integers $n > m \ge 1$ of opposite parity, with $n^2-2mn-m^2=-1$, and four pairwise relatively prime odd positive integers defined by

$$\begin{align}
 a &= 5n^2+4mn+m^2  \\
 b &= n^2-4mn+5m^2  \\
 c &= \frac{n^2-2mn+3m^2}{3}  \\
 d &= \frac{17n^2+14mn+3m^2}{3}
\end{align}$$

Is there a way to solve for $a,b,c,d$ in terms of *linear* forms in $n$ and $m$ [and $mn$, if necessary]?

Comment: What operations are allowed in the "in terms of"?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak: $n \not\equiv m\pmod{2}$.

Comment: @NDB: No restrictions, if the new expressions have no powers of $n$ or $m$!

Comment: Well, $a = 5n \cdot n + 4mn + m \cdot m$ has no powers of $n$ or $m$, but I assume that's not helpful.

Comment: @aschepler: Yeah, not helpful, thanks. I’m hoping for something like $a=15n-m$ or $a=17n+9m+2$ or similar…

Comment: Well, you can't equate a non-linear function to a linear function.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak: No… $n=3$ and $m=5$ are coprime but not of opposite parity.

Comment: @aschepler: So far, I‘ve proven $a-b+4=16mn$, and that‘s already something!

Comment: @KierenMacMillan The missing condition that you just added into the question makes a big difference. One step farther, you [can](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7B5+n%5E2+%2B+4+m+n+%2B+m%5E2+-+a%2C+n%5E2+-+4+m+n+%2B+5+m%5E2+-+b%2C+n%5E2+-+2+m+n+-+m%5E2+%2B+1%7D%2C+%7Ba%2C+b%7D%2C+%7Bm%2C+n%7D%5D) get $a^2 - 34 a b + b^2 + 144 = 0$. But that will still not give you linear solutions in $m,n$, and I don't know why you believe such solutions would exist.

Comment: There's also $10a-2b+9c-9d=0$, if that's at all useful.

Comment: $2a-9c=-7+28mn$, $d-5c=-4-16mn$.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan FWIW the condition on $n,m$ can be written as $(n-m)^2 = 2m^2 -1$. That's a [negative Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_negative_Pell's_equation) with a known set of solutions, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485341/confirmation-of-proof-2a-n2-1-left-b-n2-forall-n-in-mathbbn-1). It might help if you provided some context on what prompted the question.

Comment: @dxiv: I wouldn‘t say I *believe* such solutions would exist… simply *hope(d)*. The reductions to expressions in only $mn$ that Gerry Myerson found may be helpful.